# Getting "Fatal error in , line 0 # Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 178414678" for a nested for loop

Tags: javascript

So I have this simple Javascript code where I am comparing database-stored cart items with client-sent new cart items. But I am getting this new error which I have never seen before:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 178414678
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000DCF17BE620
 1: 00007FF7F50A401F v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+112511
 2: 00007FF7F4FC116F v8::CFunctionInfo::HasOptions+7055
 3: 00007FF7F5C97302 V8_Fatal+162
 4: 00007FF7F5820C65 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray+101
 5: 00007FF7F56CA463 v8::internal::FeedbackNexus::ic_state+62771
 6: 00007FF7F56E0FC0 v8::Message::GetIsolate+15840
 7: 00007FF7F5555681 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+26849
 8: 00007FF7F59F34B1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
 9: 000001F9C44485C2
```

What the code does is, it checks if the product id is same or not in both the arrays. If it is then it will just replace the `database cart item` unit with `client-sent cart item` unit. If it is not, then it will just push the `client-sent cart item` to `database-stored cart items` array. That's all it does.

The code:

```
const dbCartItems = [
    { productID: '1233433', unit: 1 },
    { productID: 'asfa34wr', unit: 2 }
];

const clientCartItems = [
    { productID: 'dfhgdf46t3', unit: 4 },
    { productID: 'hgfh566', unit: 1 },
    { productID: '32523', unit: 1 }
];

for ( let i = 0; i < dbCartItems.length; i++ ) {

    for ( let j = 0; j < clientCartItems.length; j++ ) {

        if ( dbCartItems[ i ].productID === clientCartItems[ j ].productID ) {
            dbCartItems[ i ].unit = clientCartItems[ j ].unit;
        } else {
            dbCartItems.push( clientCartItems[ j ] );
        }

    }

}

console.log( dbCartItems );
```

Can someone please explain what is wrong with the code that it throws this kind of error which I have never seen before?

Comment: `dbCartItems.push( clientCartItems[ j ] );` You keep increasing the length of the array inside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your complete logic is wrong. You are using nested loops and that would fetch wrong results even if you use a new array to store items in it.

Your code should look like this:

```
// get all product ids from dbCartItems array
const dbCartItemsProductIds = dbCartItems.map(cartItem => cartItem.productID);

for(let i=0;i<clientCartItems.length;i++) {
    const indexOfClientItemInDb = dbCartItemsProductIds.indexOf(clientCartItems[i].productID);
    // if clientCartItemProductId found in dbCartItemsProductIds
    if(indexOfClientItemInDb!== -1) {
        dbCartItems[indexOfClientItemInDb].unit = clientCartItems[i].unit;
    } else {
        dbCartItems.push(clientCartItems[i]);
    }
}
```

First, get all the `productIds` from `dbCartItems` (to match the `productids` from `clientCartItems`. Now, for each `clientCartItems`, check if the item product id is present in `dbCartItemsProductIds`, then change number of units, else add the item to `dbCartItems`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the «what is wrong with the code that it throws this kind of error» part of the question (particularly, _why_ the error occurs).

Answer (score 2):

You are continously adding to the same array which is resulting to an infinite loop. Make a new array and add items to it.

Comment: No, his complete logic is wrong. That also would fetch him the incorrect array.

Comment: Yeah, @Aditya is right. It produces wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue in my Angular app (upgraded from Angular version 13 to 14):

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169242095
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000A21E2FE930
 1: 00007FF7CCF1401F v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+112511
 2: 00007FF7CCE3116F v8::CFunctionInfo::HasOptions+7055
 3: 00007FF7CDB07302 V8_Fatal+162
 4: 00007FF7CD690C65 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray+101
 5: 00007FF7CD53A463 v8::internal::FeedbackNexus::ic_state+62771
 6: 00007FF7CD550FC0 v8::Message::GetIsolate+15840
 7: 00007FF7CD3C5681 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+26849
 8: 00007FF7CD8634B1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
 9: 000001D976B66A25
```

I have updated the version of `@types/node` to LTS. And this problem has been solved. I think the version was unsupportable to Angular 14v

Comment: helpful answer~

Comment: I feel like typescript types change would be quite unlikely to cause this type of runtime change, no?

Answer (score 1):

if faced this issue in Angular-js, React-js or any other js framework.

- delete node_modules
- install node_modules (npm i)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

move few dependencies to devDependencies.

For my react Project, solution was to:

move "react-scripts": "5.0.1" from dependencies to devDependencies in package.json